# typeScript function skipping first value which is 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this function below in angular 7

```
setPaginationIndexes(ending: Number, starting: Number) {
    debugger
    if (this.fileJson.length > ending)
      this.loopIndexesEnd = Array(ending).fill(ending).map((x, i) => {
        if (i >= starting) { return i }
      });
    else
      this.loopIndexesEnd = Array(this.fileJson.length).fill(this.fileJson.length).map((x, i) => {
        if (i >= starting) { return i }
      });
      this.loopIndexesEnd = this.loopIndexesEnd.filter((value, index)=>{ // In this function it is skipping zero although the condition is true and it returns the 0 value.
        if(value != undefined)
          return value
      })

  }
```

Im calling it by passing setPaginationIndexes(100,0)

The resulted array should be starting from 0 value.

```
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

but the resulted array is

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
```

I have mentioned in the comment where it skips the zero value. Problem is in filter function. Im not getting the issue here, perhaps if someone can explain to me.

Comment: `.filter()` expects a callback that returns `true` or `false`. When you `return 0`, that's falsy and thus the result is skipped.

Comment: @VLAZ  yes it did resolve my issue. thanks a lot. I was under an impression I needed to return the actual value when in fact I needed to return true or false.

Comment: Simplify your function as `function setPaginationIndexes(ending, starting) { let arrayLength = Math.min(fileJson.length, ending); return Array(arrayLength-starting).fill(arrayLength).map((x, i) => i+starting); }`, and it will work as expected.